# Is every metrizable space a $P$-space?

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ called $P$-space if every $G_\delta$ subset of $X$ is open in $X$. Then is every metrizable space a $P$-space? Thanks ahead:)

Comment: Points (and closed sets) in a metrizable space are $G_\delta$. Are points (and closed sets) open in every metrizable space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $\mathbb R$, any singleton is a $G_\delta$ set, so not every metrizable space is a $P$-space.

Just in case you are asking whether a metrizable space exists which is also a $P$-space, then the answer is yes, any discrete space will do the job.

Comment: In fact, the metrizable P-spaces are exactly the discrete spaces.

Comment: yes, if you demand $d(x,y)=0\implies x=y$.